# Laravel 5.6 Validation not working

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to validate my form, and if there's an error, looks like it stops the code from running.

When I try this one it shows the `$request`:

```
public function create(Request $request){

  dd($request);

  $validation = $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u|max:255',
                'status' => 'required',
            ]);
}
```

But when I try to dd after the `$validation`, it won't show as if it ignores the codes after the `$validation`. Whatever I try to echo after the $validation won't display

```
public function create(Request $request){

      $validation = $request->validate([
                    'name' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u|max:255',
                    'status' => 'required',
                ]);


      //These lines wont display in the browser
      dd($validation);
      echo 'test';
}
```

And the errors wont show in the view either.

```
@if ($errors->any())
        <script>
            $('#addModal').modal('show')
        </script>
    @endif
```

Comment: From the Laravel docs - `As you can see, we pass the desired validation rules into the validate method. Again, if the validation fails, the proper response will automatically be generated. If the validation passes, our controller will continue executing normally.`

Comment: Yes, but `@if ($errors->any())` won't work in the view either.

Comment: Is the `web` middleware applied to the controller actions in your routes file?

Comment: By default, the web middleware is applied to all actions